# User's locale in microservice - JHipster

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, jhipster, microservices

In one of the microservices, in a JHipster microservice architecture, I want to generate a document, in the users' language.

In the gateway, the users' language is retrieved by a cookie (AngularCookieLocaleResolver). But when a request, routed through the gateway, arrives at the microservice, no cookies are found on the request.

I see a few options here:

1. Add a locale claim to the JWT-token
2. Contact the gateway with the username, to retrieve the locale
3. Do not generate locale specific content at a microservice

I would prefer the first option, but maybe there are some better options...

Can anyone help me choose or list up alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

First option using JWT claim makes sense and it could be proposed as an enhancement request to JHipster project. I can see one minor drawback: any user changing her locale won't get correct localised content until token expires or she logs out and re-authenticates.

An alternative would be to pass the locale as a parameter of your resources requests, this makes sense as client is supposed to know it and also in a broader scope client could a be a partner application using another kind of authentication like an API key.